# how to trigger a c++ function in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have one more question in connection with my QVariantMap. Currently I trigger the filling directly at startup (c++):

```
StyleConfiguration::StyleConfiguration(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    restore("q_button");
}
```

However, I would like to have the map filled directly at runtime in qlm, but don't know how to manage that.

Somethings like this:

xxxx: _styleconfiguration.restore("q_button")
Similar to a repeater:

```
    Repeater{
          model: _styleconfiguration.restore("q_button")
   }
```

what should I use for xxx? Would be happy if someone can help me further.

addition:

**mainWin.qml:**

```
Rectangle {
    id: dashboard
    ...
    
    Row {
        ...  
                
        //----------------Button-------------//
        Grid {
        
           ....

            Component.onCompleted: _styleconfiguration.readValue("q_button")  // **<- Call to read out the json**

            Repeater {
                id: dashboardButtons
                model: _configuration.buttonMapping

                Q_Button{                                                     // **<- use read out values from the json**
                    id: dashButton

                    text: dashboard.functionsDashboard[modelData].text
                    
                   ...
                    
                }
            }  
        }
    }
    
    //----------------Longpress Menu-------------//
    Popup {      
       ...  
        contentItem: Rectangle {
           ...    
            Column {
               ....
                Component.onCompleted: _styleconfiguration.readValue("l_button")
                
                Repeater {
                    model: dashboard.functionsDashboard

                    L_Button {

                        text: modelData.text.replace('\n', ' ')
                        
                        ....
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Q_Button.qml**:

```
Rectangle {

    id: button

    width: _styleconfiguration.styleMapping["width"]
    height: _styleconfiguration.styleMapping["height"]
   ...

}
```

I hope the addition helps for understanding

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely...

You have to mark your method declaration as Q_INVOKABLE in order to call it from QML:

Q_INVOKABLE void restore(const QString& s);

Then you can call it at creation of your QML Component.

Component.onCompleted: _styleconfiguration.restore("q_button")

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: If this answers your question, then please mark it as resolved.

Comment: @ avb: I have now inserted the call to the relevant places and now get the following problem: with the call of the function, the necessary properties of a button are read from a json - which works so far. But now the values of the last used function call are used exclusively. I thought that the values are used directly after the call of the function. Am I completely wrong? I am sorry if I should have expressed myself a little unclearly.

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to achieve. Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @avb: The basic idea is the following: I want to read the definition (width, height etc) of my buttons from a json and then use these values in the qml. I have now created a separate qml for each button type (Q_Button.qml, L_Button.qml etc.) There I would now like to use the values - each with the call suggested by you. My problem is that Q_Button does not use the values for q_button from the json, instead it uses the values from l_button, because these values were read last from the json. My question: How can I use the values read from the json directly in the respective qml?

Comment: Can you provide more of your QML code? Although your comment describe roughly you use case, I can't get the full picture from it....

Comment: @avb: I have expanded the question

Comment: You use functionsDashboard but in you code it is unclear what functionsDashboard is.

Comment: I think I have found the error. I assumed that Qt runs sequentially similar to c++. This is probably not the case. I guess I will cache the needed values instead of using them directly